How to clean triangulated model?
I don't know how to clean this triangulated model if anyone know please tell me.


Alt J is to untriangulate but it won't fix all your tris, i'm afraid you'll need to rework manually

I tried that, but not working properly. Anyway, thank you for your comment

I'm guessing you can't let us demonstrate some suggestions by sharing on  https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

"I tried that, but not working properly." - I believe the suggestion was to use untriangulate and then manually fix and remodel parts that it doesn't work for. How can this be not working properly? That's also pretty much the only solution that makes sense. I don't think you will get another answer. If you shared the file like Robin Betts suggested, you might only get some more detailed explanations of what exact functions and tools to use...
